# find the recurrence relation of a string

Tags: recurrence-relations

So I got this problem: compute the number of n bit string that do not contain pattern 010 that have no leading 0, one leading zero, two leading zero, and so on.

So far, I got the expression:

```
Sn = Sn-1 + Sn-3 + Sn-4...+ S1
```

However the solution is:

```
Sn = Sn-1 + Sn-3 + Sn-4...+ S1 + 3
```

My question is, where + 3 come from? thx

update:
I was thinking that if the string that does not contain 010 begin w/ 1, the rest will be Sn-1.
if the string begin with one 0 (which mean the first two bit is 01), the next bit have to be 0 -> Sn-3
and so on

Comment: It would help to see how you got your answer.  It is easier to check that way.  Clearly it is not right as S1=2 and S2 can't be 5-there aren't that many strings.  But S2 is 4, and your recurrence would make it 2

Comment: @rossmilikan edited. as u can see, there's no S0 -> so, S1 is the init, S1 = 1. S2 = 1 + 3 =4

Comment: I'm not understanding your definition of Sn.  It seems both $0$ and $1$ are legal one bit strings, so S1 should be 2, and all four two bit strings are still legal, so S2 should be 4.

Comment: if n=0, there's no string at all. which mean the number of occurrence of a string that not contain 010 is 0. Honestly, I don't rly get this problem too :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define $00(n)$ as the number of n bit strings that start with $00$ and do not include $010$, and $10(n), 01(n),$ and $11(n)$ similarly.  Then $S(n)$ the total number of $n$ bit strings is the sum of these.  We then have $$00(2)=10(2)=01(2)=11(2)=1\\00(n)=01(n-1)+00(n-1)\\01(n)=11(n-1)\\10(n)=00(n-1)+01(n-1)\\11(n)=10(n-1)+11(n-1)$$  It is curious (and easy to prove) that $11(n)=S(n-2)$.  The recurrence should be solvable by diagonalizing the matrix.  The growth rate is the square of the [plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html), about $1.754877666$  It is also the real root of $x^3-2x^2+x-1=0$

Added:  It starts $1,2,4,7,12,21,37,65,114,200,351.  This is [OEIS A005251](http://oeis.org/A005251) where there is more description.